# How to change parent component content on clicking a button in child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment, antd, react-props

I am new to react and,
I have an antd Popover, that displays components A, B and C.

```
<Popover
        content={
          <>
            <A />
            <B />
            <C />
          </>
        }
/>
```

On clicking a button in component B , only component D (new) must be displayed in Popover.

This is B Component

```
const B = () => {
const [subScreen, setSubScreen] = useState(false);
onClick =() => {
setSubScreen(true);
}
return(
  <button onClick={onClick}> Click me!</button>
  { subScreen ? <D /> : null }
);
};

export default B;
```

This is Component D

```
const D = () => {
onClick =() => {
// Popovers content should be A,B and C
}
return(
  <>
  <button onClick={onClick}> Display A,B and C</button>
  <h1> Component D </h1>
  </>
);
};
export default D;
```

On clicking the button in component D, the popover must display A,B,C.
I am not able to understand how to do it.
Anyone please help!!

Comment: You need to hoist your state up the tree and pass callbacks into the children that can update the state.

You can use the state to render either A, B, C or D

The button(s) can be used to invoke the callback that will toggle the state.

Answer (score 2):

To lift the state up can solve this

```
const B = () => {
  const [subScreen, setSubScreen] = useState(false);
  const onClick =() => {
    setSubScreen(true);
  }
  const onBack =() => {
    setSubScreen(false);
  }
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}> Click me!</button>
      { subScreen ? <D rollBack={onBack} /> : null }
    </div>

);
};
const D = (props) => {
  const onClick =() => {
// Popovers content should be A,B and C
    props.rollBack()
  }
  return(
    <>
      <button onClick={onClick}> Display A,B and C</button>
      <h1> Component D </h1>
    </>
  );
};
```